# JSF managed bean redirect with parameters without viewing URL

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, managed-bean

I'm trying to redirect from one jsf to another by redirecting from the managed bean as folows:

```
return "page2?faces-redirect=true&parameter1=a&parameter2=b";
```

but I can see the parameters in the url. Is it possible to redirect to page2 but without viewing the passed parameters?

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Store them in a cookie or the session.